# jOOQ - join with nested subquery

Tags: java, sql, jooq, subquery

Let's say I want to find out who wrote `CLRS` in a book db (tables `BOOK`, `AUTHOR` with a junction table `BOOK_AUTHOR`).

```java
SelectConditionStep<Record1<String>> query = create
        .select(AUTHOR.LASTNAME.as("AuthorName"))
            .from(
                    (
                            BOOK.leftOuterJoin(BOOK_AUTHOR).on(BOOK.ID.eq(BOOK_AUTHOR.BOOKID))
                    ).leftOuterJoin(AUTHOR).on(AUTHOR.ID.eq(BOOK_AUTHOR.AUTHORID))
            )
            .where(BOOK.TITLE.eq(CLRS_title))
        ;
```

A bit inefficient to match the entire table, just to select a single book. I now want to select that book prior to the match.

[The jOOQ doc on this matter](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/nested-selects/) led me to believe that could look something like this:

```java
Table<Record1<Integer>> clrs = create
        .select(BOOK.ID.as("bookID"))
            .from(BOOK)
            .where(BOOK.TITLE.eq(CLRS_title))

        .asTable()
        ;

SelectJoinStep<Record1<String>> query = create
        .select(AUTHOR.LASTNAME.as("AuthorName"))
            .from(
                    (
                            clrs.leftOuterJoin(BOOK_AUTHOR).on(clrs.field("bookID").eq(BOOK_AUTHOR.BOOKID))
                    ).leftOuterJoin(AUTHOR).on(AUTHOR.ID.eq(BOOK_AUTHOR.AUTHORID))
            )
        ;
```

However, that fails to compile because

```
Cannot resolve method 'eq(org.jooq.TableField<ch.cypherk.bookdb.public_.tables.records.BookAuthorRecord,java.lang.Integer>)'
```

in the join condition.

What's the correct way to write this join?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The problem you're having

You're dereferencing a column from your derived table using [`Table.field(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableLike.html#field-java.lang.String-):

```java
clrs.field("bookID")
```

The type you're getting back is `Field<?>`, with a wildcard. Like with any generic type, once you have a wild card, a lot of operations (but not all) will no longer be possible on that type. Take `List<?>`, for example. You can still call `List<?>.get()` to retrieve an `Object`, but not `List<?>.add(? element)`. In `Field<?>`, you can no longer call `eq()`, unless you cast the argument to a raw type.

You can also coerce your field's `<T>` type to the type you already know, e.g. by using [`Table.field(String, DataType<T>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TableLike.html#field-java.lang.String-org.jooq.DataType-)

```java
clrs.field("bookID", BOOK.ID.getDataType())
```

Study your various options and you might discover the one(s) you might find most useful

#### A better solution to your query

You don't really need to

1. Assign your subquery to a local variable
2. Use a derived table for your problem

Often with jOOQ, if you're having issues with derived tables as above, ask yourself is there really not an easier query I could write instead?

What you really need here is a [semi join](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/10/13/semi-join-and-anti-join-should-have-its-own-syntax-in-sql/). Write:

```java
// Assuming this static import
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

ctx.select(AUTHOR.LASTNAME)
   .from(AUTHOR)
   .where(AUTHOR.ID.in(
        select(BOOK_AUTHOR.AUTHORID)
       .from(BOOK_AUTHOR)
       .join(BOOK).on(BOOK.ID.eq(BOOK_AUTHOR.BOOKID))
       .where(BOOK.TITLE.eq(clrsTitle))
   )
   .fetch();
```

Comment: I appreciate that you helped the questioner find a simpler way to solve their problem.  My query cannot be simplified in that way.  Would you mind providing a solution to their original question?  I need to join to the multi-column result of a nested subselect.  I have searched for about an hour for the answer.  I have found several articles on the JOOQ blog about nested subqueries and very short docs pages, but none of them contain full usable examples.

Comment: @M.Leonhard: Rather than editing this answer, I'll be happy to answer your own, specific question